# OpenCart + Docker не открывается /admin

Tags: nginx, docker, opencart, ocstore

Появилась потребность поставить OpenCart Store на докер. При переносе сайта взял дамп бд с продакшена, полностью скопировал все файлы. Залил бд себе, поменял в конфигах доступы к бд. Переписал пути в обоих конфигах.

**site/config.php**

```html
<?php
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://localhost/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'https://localhost/');

// DIR
define('DIR_APPLICATION', '/var/www/site/catalog/');
define('DIR_SYSTEM', '/var/www/site/system/');
define('DIR_IMAGE', '/var/www/site/image/');
define('DIR_LANGUAGE', '/var/www/site/catalog/language/');
define('DIR_TEMPLATE', '/var/www/site/catalog/view/theme/');
define('DIR_CONFIG', '/var/www/site/system/config/');
define('DIR_CACHE', '/var/www/site/system/storage/cache/');
define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', '/var/www/site/system/storage/download/');
define('DIR_LOGS', '/var/www/site/system/storage/logs/');
define('DIR_MODIFICATION', '/var/www/site/system/storage/modification/');
define('DIR_UPLOAD', '/var/www/site/system/storage/upload/');
```

**site/admin/config.php**

```html
<?php
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://localhost/admin/');
define('HTTP_CATALOG', 'http://localhost/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'https://localhost/admin/');
define('HTTPS_CATALOG', 'https://localhost/');

// DIR
define('DIR_APPLICATION', '/var/www/site/admin/');
define('DIR_SYSTEM', '/var/www/site/system/');
define('DIR_IMAGE', '/var/www/site/image/');
define('DIR_LANGUAGE', '/var/www/site/admin/language/');
define('DIR_TEMPLATE', '/var/www/site/admin/view/template/');
define('DIR_CONFIG', '/var/www/site/system/config/');
define('DIR_CACHE', '/var/www/site/system/storage/cache/');
define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', '/var/www/site/system/storage/download/');
define('DIR_LOGS', '/var/www/site/system/storage/logs/');
define('DIR_MODIFICATION', '/var/www/site/system/storage/modification/');
define('DIR_UPLOAD', '/var/www/site/system/storage/upload/');
define('DIR_CATALOG', '/var/www/site/catalog/');
```

**Конфигурация nginx**

```html
server {

    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    server_name localhost;
    root /var/www/site/;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

      location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_pass php-upstream;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Главная страница **работает**, при переходе на страницу /admin - Запрашиваемая страница не найдена!

Подскажите как исправить. 
Контактный тг @rgvldi

Comment: В нджинкс пробовал добавлять   
  location /admin/ {
        index index.php;
    } не помогло

Comment: А вы так https на http  и не перебили в конфигах?

Answer (score 0):

```
location / { try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args; }
```